# Background inner fade

Tags: html, css

I have a background image [HERE](http://s28.postimg.org/qv8nz449p/sidebar_bg.png) for a sidebar. 
Want to make this background using only CSS, is this possible?

Height of the sidebar, is changing depending on the content `<div>`

That's why I can't use background image.

Comment: Low research and effort. Look up css3 gradient, my personal favorite is on css-tricks.com

Comment: You could just do a repeat-y and have the image repeat down the height of the `<div>` but there are ways to accomplish this in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box-shadow to get that effect.

```
   background-color:#880600;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 5px 20px 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 5px 20px 5px black;
   box-shadow:inset 0px 5px 20px 5px black;
```

http://jsbin.com/bapawoho/1/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The bottom edge is not really identical to the OP's image. (there should not any fade/shadow at the bottom edge).

Answer (score 2):

one possibility is, you can combine css gradient and box shadow.
the css gradient will give LHS RHS shade and box shadow will give TOP shade.
hence the bottom edge can be kept identical to OP image.
here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y7XHe/)**

```
.shadow_grad
{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  //shadow
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0) inset;
  //gradient part included in fiddle, cant paste here as its long

}
```